# Ada Generic Package with Default Subprogram

Tags: generics, ada

I am trying to create an Ada generic package that has a subprogram parameter with a default value. I cant get the compiler to recognize the default value.. Im guessing this is due to visibility. Is there a way to forward declare a function within the generic declaration?

The Generic Spec:

```
generic
    type Item is private;
    type Item_Ref is access all Item;
    Addr : System.Address;
    Default : Item;

    with Is_Valid (Obj : Item) return Boolean;

    -- Forward Declare ** DOES NOT COMPILE
    function Default_Validate (Data_Ptr : Item_Ref) return Boolean;

    with function Validate (Data_Ptr : Item_Ref) return Boolean is Default_Validate;

package Foo is

    -- function Default_Validate (Data_Ptr : Item_Ref) return Boolean;

    function Read_Eeprom return Item;

end Foo;
```

The Generic Body:

```
package body Foo is

    Obj : aliased Item;
    for Obj'Address use Addr;

    -- Read Method
    function Read_Eeprom return Item is
    begin

        -- ** Read EEPROM using OBJ **

        Validate (Obj'Unchecked_Access);

    end Read_Eeprom;

    -- Default Validate Method
    function Default_Validate (Data_Ptr : Item_Ref) return Boolean is 
        Valid : Boolean;
    begin
        Valid := Is_Valid(Data_Ptr.all);

        if not Valid then
            Data_Ptr.all := Default;
        end if;

        return Valid;
    end Default_Validate;

end Foo;
```

Driver

```
with Foo;
procedure Main is
    MAX_INT : constant Integer := 100;
    MIN_INT : constant Integer := 0;

    -- Special / Non-Scaler Type
    type Pair_Type is 
        record
            X : Integer;
            Y : Integer;
        end record;

    type Pair_Ref is access all Pair;

    -- Is Valid
    function Int_Is_Valid(Int : Integer) return Boolean is
    begin 
        return (Int <= MAX_INT and Int >= MIN_INT);
    end Pair_Is_Valid;

    -- Is Valid
    function Pair_Is_Valid(Pair : Pair_Type) return Boolean is
    begin 
        return Pair.X'Valid and Pair.Y'Valid;
    end Pair_Is_Valid;

    -- Validate
    function Pair_Validate(Pair : Pair_Ref) return Boolean is
        Valid : Boolean := True;
    begin
        if not Pair.X'Valid then
            Pair.X := 0;
            Valid := False;
        end if;

        if not Pair.Y'Valid then
            Pair.Y := 0;
            Valid := False;
        end if;

        return Valid;
    end Special_Validate;

    type Int_Ref is access all Integer;

    My_Int  : Integer;
    My_Pair : Pair_Type;
    Default_Pair : Pair_Type := (0,0);

    package Int_Obj is new Foo (Item => Integer,
                                Item_Ref => Int_Ref,
                                Addr => My_Int'Address,
                                Default => 0,
                                Is_Valid => Int_Is_Valid);

    package Pair_Obj is new Foo (Item => Pair_Type,
                                 Item_Ref => Pair_Ref,
                                 Addr => My_Pair'Address,
                                 Default => Default_Pair,
                                 Is_Valid => Pair_Is_Valid,
                                 Validate => Pair_Validate);

   Tmp_Int   : Integer;
   Tmps_Pair : Pair_Type;

begin

   Tmp_Int := Int_Obj.Read_Eeprom;
   Tmp_Pair := Pair_Obj.Read_Eeprom;

end Main;
```

The error Im getting is "end of file expected, file can only have one compilation unit"
How can I default a generic subprogram to a function that is a member of the package?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can't--it's a chicken-and-egg problem.  The compiler needs to figure out what all the generic parameters are going to be before it can instantiate the generic; but the `Default_Validate` method will not become available until *after* the generic is instantiated.  The closest I think you can come is to declare two generics:

```
generic
    type Item is private;
    type Item_Ref is access all Item;
    with function Validate (Data_Ptr : Item_Ref) return Boolean;   
package Foo is

    function Default_Validate (Data_Ptr : Item_Ref) return Boolean;
    -- etc.

end Foo;

generic
    type Item is private;
    type Item_Ref is access all Item;
package Foo_With_Default_Validator is
    -- important procedure/function declarations from Foo
end Foo_With_Default_Validator;

package body Foo_With_Default_Validator is
    function Default_Validate (Data_Ptr : Item_Ref) return boolean;
    package My_Foo is new Foo(Item, Item_Ref, Default_Validate);  
    function Default_Validate (Data_Ptr : Item_Ref) return boolean
        renames My_Foo.Default_Validate;
    -- and other procedures/functions will be renames of things from My_Foo
end Foo_With_Default_Validator;
```

(I haven't tested this yet.  **EDIT:** tested, compiles OK.)  I'm assuming here that the only publicly visible things in Foo are procedures and functions.  If there are other important features (such as types), it gets more complicated, and then you might have to use nested generics, where `with function Validate` gets moved off the outer generic into an inner generic, or you might be able to use a generic formal package to split the generic into two parts.  In either of those cases, the user of the generic might have to perform two instantiations.  If the above solution works, then a user will instantiate either `Foo` or `Foo_With_Default_Validator`, but it would be one or the other--two instantiations wouldn't be needed.  If you need more assistance, I think we'd need to see the visible part of `Foo`.

**EDIT 2:**  Here's a solution if you're willing to require an `'Access` attribute when instantiating:

```
generic
    type Item is private;
    type Item_Ref is access all Item;
    Validate : access function (Data_Ptr : Item_Ref) return Boolean := null;   
package Foo is

    function Default_Validate (Data_Ptr : Item_Ref) return Boolean;
    -- etc.

end Foo;
```

Then in the body of `Foo`, you'll want a function like this:

```
function Perform_Validate (Data_Ptr : Item_Ref) return Boolean is
begin
    if Validate = null
        then return Default_Validate (Data_Ptr);
        else return Validate (Data_Ptr);
    end if;
end Perform_Validate;
```

and call `Perform_Validate` from the rest of the body whenever you want to call the validation function.  (`Perform_Validate` could be written more concisely using new Ada 2012 features, but you get the idea.)

Comment: Sorry I didnt specify that I was looking for an Ada95 compliant solution. Your second solution wont work due to subprograms not allowed to be null in Ada95.

Comment: Ada 95 doesn't allow the anonymous access-to-subprogram generic formal parameter at all (even without the `:= null`).

Answer (score 1):

As you have it, the generic is defining a function, `Default_Validate`, because keyword **`function`** is *not* preceded by **`with`**. What you should have is this:

```ada
generic
    type Item is private;
    type Item_Ref is access all Item;

    with function Default_Validate (Data_Ptr : Item_Ref) return Boolean;
    -- A function "Validate", which defaults to 'Default_Validate'.
    with function Validate (Data_Ptr : Item_Ref) return Boolean is Default_Validate;
package Foo is
    -- function Default_Validate (Data_Ptr : Item_Ref) return Boolean;
end Foo;
```

---

**EDIT:**

The comments clarified that the previous was not what you want. The form above would be used in cases where you have a possibly-overriding validator and a default one w/o having to resort to using tagged types (Ada's terminology for instances of OOP classes).

Instead what you want is for the parameters to possibly take subprograms from the visible subprograms as defaults for the formal parameters, the following does so:

```ada
generic
    type Item is private;
    type Item_Ref is access all Item;

    -- A function "Validate", which defaults to 'Validate'. The function
    -- needs to be visible when the generic is instantiated, not here
    -- where the generic is defined.
    with function Validate (Data_Ptr : Item_Ref) return Boolean is <>;
package Foo is
    -- Just a stub.
end Foo;

    Type Some_Integer_Access is access all Integer;
    function Validate (Data_Ptr : Some_Integer_Access) return Boolean is (true);


    Package K is new Foo( Item     => Integer,
                          Item_Ref => Some_Integer_Access
            );
```

But even this might be improved:

```ada
generic
    type Item is private;
    with function Validate (Data_Ptr : not null access Item) return Boolean is <>;
package Foo is
    -- Just a stub.
end Foo;


    function Validate (Data_Ptr : not null access Integer) return Boolean is (true);

    -- One parameter! Ah! Ah, Ah!
    Package K is new Foo( Item => Integer );
```

Comment: Note that following `is` your function can also name an attribute. So if you had a scalar type for Item (and changed it to `(<>)` instead of `private`) you could say: `with function Image( X: Item ) return String is Item'Image;`. See [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Generics#Generic_formal_types).

Comment: I'm not sure this is helpful ... I think the idea of putting a default for the generic formal subprogram was so that it could be instantiated with just the first two parameters, without having to set up a `Validate` function at all, and to have the default be a function defined *by* the generic.  This solution pretty much defeats the purpose, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @ajb is right. This wasnt really what I was looking for. I was trying to forward declare the local Validate function. Your solution requires that I provide the "common" validate function as a generioc paramter.

Comment: @Shark8 Im not sure this works either. It would seem I would have to define a validate function for each instance of a generic even if Im not passing it in as a paramter. The point of having the default function in the generic was to eliminate duplicate code. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not sure this works either. It would seem I would have to define a validate function for each instance of a generic even if I'm not passing it in as a parameter.

That is probably the *best* way to approach this; you're talking validation of data after all... and defaulting that could have unexpected behavior. (Any type that's crossing in/out of your system ought to be validated; e.g. File reads, DB reads, user-input, etc.)

> The point of having the default function in the generic was to eliminate duplicate code. Any other thoughts?

Well, there is one method that springs to mind. It requires us to limit what we accept in our generic though. My other solutions are [almost] fully generalized and therefore would work on any non-limited type.

Taking the attribute `'Valid` we see that the [documentation](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05aarm/html/AA-13-9-2.html) says this:
`The Valid attribute can be used to check the validity of data produced by unchecked conversion, input, interface to foreign languages, and the like.`

So we have a default validation, of sorts.
We also have a way to have attributes stand in for the default of function formal-parameters.
We have a way to default to visible functions.
Last we have nested generics.

Now there's no generic formal type `scalar`, which would be useful here... but we have a way to limit the type of a formal parameter `Type T(<>) is (<>)` is limited to integral numerics, modular-types, and enumerations... all of which we know are scalar-types.

```
Generic
    Type Item(<>) is (<>);
Package Generic_Base is
    -- To use this as a Ada-95 pkg delete everything after 'Boolean',
    -- create a body and return X'Valid from the implementation.
    Function Default_Validate(X : Item) Return Boolean is (X'Valid);

    Generic
        with function Validate(X:Item) return Boolean is Default_Validate;
    Package Generic_Nested is
        -- Operations requiring validation.
    End Generic_Nested;

End Generic_Base;
```

Using these packages would be as follows:

```
Package Base is new Generic_Base( Integer );
Package Nested is new Base.Generic_Nested;
```

If you're happy in limiting the formal parameter to integrals/modulars/enumerations, this should work.

So, there you go.

---

Recommended reading:

### [Ada's Generic Formal Type System](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Generics#Generic_formal_types)

---

<sup>No syntax highlighting because it looks ***terrible*** on this.</sup>

Comment: I added additional code to help clarify the result I am trying to achieve. Forcing Scalar types is not really an option.

Comment: Then it seems you have conflicting goals: either you want a general generic solution [already provided] which means you *must* supply a Validate function [though that can default if it is visible at the point of instantiation] **OR** you want a solution where you do not have to specify a validate function with your type [and in so doing eliminate the type being a non-scalar].

Comment: I wouldn't say my goals are conflicting. You make it sound as if Im trying to do something wrong. All Im merely trying to do is eliminate duplicate code. I have about 50 instantiations of this generic where about 15 instances of require their own special Validate functions. All I want is for the other 35 instances to use the same common code to validate. If it's not possible and the language doesnt support what I want, then just say that.

Answer (score 1):

You really keep moving the goalposts. Your new additions are, in a word, terrible: they don't compile at all and they are a smattering of obviously cut-and-pasted code as evidenced by mismatching function-names (e.g. `Int_Is_Valid`/`Pair_Is_Valid`).

First, let's use a signature-package.

`signature.ads`

```
generic
    Type Item is private;
    Default : in Item;
package SIGNATURE is
end SIGNATURE;
```

`foo.ads`

```
with
System,
SIGNATURE;

generic
    with package Item_Pkg is new SIGNATURE(<>);

    Addr     : System.Address;

    with function Is_Valid(X : Item_Pkg.Item) return Boolean is <>;
package Foo is
    use Item_Pkg;

    function Read_Eeprom return Item;
    function Is_Valid (Data_Ptr : access Item) return Boolean;

private
    Port : Item;    
    pragma Volatile( Port );
    Pragma Import( Convention => Ada, Entity => Port );

    For Port'Address Use Addr;
end Foo;
```

`foo.adb`

```
package body Foo is

    function Read_Eeprom return Item is
        Result : constant Item:= Port;
    begin
        if Is_Valid(Result) then
            return Result;
        else
            return Default;
        end if;
    end Read_Eeprom;

    function Is_Valid (Data_Ptr : access Item) return Boolean is
    begin
        return Is_Valid(Data_Ptr.all);
    end Is_Valid;

end Foo;
```

`driver.ads`

```
package Driver is
    MAX_INT                : constant Integer := 100;
    MIN_INT                : constant Integer := 0;

    -- Special / Non-Scaler Type
    type Pair_Type is 
    record
        X                  : Integer;
        Y                  : Integer;
    end record;

    -- Is Valid **USING OVERLOADS**
    function Is_Valid(Int  : Integer  ) return Boolean;
    function Is_Valid(Pair : Pair_Type) return Boolean;

    My_Int                 : Integer;
    My_Pair                : Pair_Type;

private
    Default_Pair           : constant Pair_Type := (0,0);
    Default_Integer        : constant Integer   := 0;
end Driver;
```

`driver.adb`

```
with
Foo,
SIGNATURE;

package body Driver is

    -- Is Valid
    function Is_Valid(Int  : Integer)   return Boolean is
        (Int <= MAX_INT and Int >= MIN_INT);

    function Is_Valid(Pair : Pair_Type) return Boolean is
        (Pair.X'Valid and Pair.Y'Valid);


    package Int_pkg  is new SIGNATURE(Integer,   0);
    package Pair_Pkg is new SIGNATURE(Pair_Type, Default_Pair);

    -- Using defaults for Is_Valid.
    package Int_Obj is new Foo (Item_Pkg  => Int_Pkg,
                                Addr      => My_Int'Address
                               );
    package Pair_Obj is new Foo(Item_Pkg => Pair_Pkg,
                                Addr     => My_Pair'Address
                               );

end Driver;
```

---

Given the rather obvious structuring of your code around `access`-types, I'm guessing that you are trying to "import" knowledge from C or C++. That's going to cause you a lot of trouble/work later on if you try using Ada like it's a C-style language.

Also, it may be beneficial to sit down, take a breath, and think about things [in terms of types](http://blog.kickin-the-darkness.com/2007/08/fundamental-theory-of-ada.html) both the problem-space and, separately, the architecture.

Comment: I'm not moving the goalposts. My original example and question may have been poorky worded, but I am still trying to achievethe same result as I did when I asked the original question. I only added to example code to further explain my scenario. And yes, this is example code. I cannot post the actual code due to several constraints, which many using Ada can understand.

Comment: I read you link. THere is nothing in that post that I dont already understand. Nor do I think there is anything in my design that suggests I'm not using Types correctly. The reason for the pointers was the desire to have teh function return 2 values. Since Ada wont allow out parameters in functions, I chose to use a Pointer, which to me seems like one of the legit reasons in Ada to use pointers.

Comment: I dont get your comment about my C and C++ background causing trouble in Ada. What exactly am I trying to do is not allowed in the language. Yes, Ada is a strongly typed language and I abide by those rules, I use my types. But where in the LRM does it say to not use pointers? I have a strong OOP background. I get the Ada OOP model. I dont see what in my code deserves the above comment.

Comment: The LRM doesn't say not to use pointers, it's just that doing C/C++ programming makes pointers tend to be the very first thing in your toolbox you grab for; if you adopt a "pointers should be avoided at near all costs" mentality then you'll tend to have a more proper balance when approaching the problem using Ada.

Comment: If you're using Ada 2012 the prohibition on out parameters was lifted; if you need to make a function returning multiple results [in earlier versions] I would suggest first using a procedure w/ `out` parameters, then wrapping that into a function... or, better-yet, using an inline declare-block.

Comment: Whats wrong with pointers? Why would someone avoid them at all costs? They are very usefull.

Comment: You misunderstand (you completely ignored the point was about balance); for *most* of what you use pointers for in C/C++ you simply don't need in Ada. Ex: Alterable parameters, `in out` or `out` modes. Array-length parameters: `Some_Array'Length`. -- So simply saying "pointers are useful" and using them to do what you've been trained to use them for by C/C++ means you aren't learning Ada, and frankly are writing Ada code that's much harder to read/maintain.

Comment: You should also note that I didn't have to use pointers at all in the above; I can simply specify the address that the item uses.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41565/discussion-between-shark8-and-jerunh)